# Number of MUX required for Cache Mapping

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I have read that the number of multiplexers required is equal to the number of bits in the TAG field. Is it true? If yes then why?

I know that the size of each multiplexer has to be ***S to 1***, where S is the number of sets in a k-way associative cache (For Direct Mapped, no. of sets = no. of lines). That's because we have to select one of the sets using the set offset (or index) bits.

I'm not being able to reason with the number of multiplexers required though.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplexer can output only a single bit on output line.
So, to output one complete tag to the comparator ,

Number of multiplexers required = Number of bits in the tag. (say T)

If there are k lines in one set, then number of tags to output = K,

thus ,

number of multiplexers required = Number of lines in one set (K) x Number of bits in the tag(T).

TOTAL MUX REQUIRED = K*T

Comment: But how do you reach that particular set? For that you need a multiplexer. Isn't it?